# Como hacer paginacion con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

intento hacer una paginacion para una app sencilla utilizando react y la api https://newsdata.io/blog/newsdata-pagination/ pero no me sale bien en el fetch me salen diez elementos pero quiero ver los demas ya que en total hay totalResults: 11181

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
export const usaNews = async () => {
try {
    const response = await fetch('https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=your_pub_api_key_here&country=us')
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

}

```
const [usa, setUsa] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
usaNews().then((data) => setUsa(data.results))
},[])
```

Comment: Alli en la documentación tienes el instructivo de como obtener la siguiente pagina, cual seria el problema?

Comment: No deberías mostrar tu API key, en especial si es una API de pago y/o con cuota. Ahora ya es pública, así que dale de baja a la clave actual y genera una nueva. No te molestes en editar la pregunta, seguirá estando en el historial de ediciones.

Comment: En [la documentación](https://newsdata.io/documentation/#latest-news) puedes ver todos los parámetros del endpoint que estás usando. [Se explica](https://newsdata.io/documentation/#pagination) que debes agregar `&page=` seguido del *ID* que viene bajo el atributo **nextPage**.

Comment: @Mateo los moderadores podemos redactar la informacion para que desaparezca para siempre. sin embargo, es cierto que una vez publica, ya fue expuesta.